# Using indexedDB in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, indexeddb

I can't manage to save data using indexedDB in a Firefox extension. I also cannot find any information about indexedDB  and Firefox extensions.

Has anyone ever dealt with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is, for `indexedDB` you need a window, other than that there is not much special when using it from an add-on. Classic add-ons usually have a window that they can use, add-ons created with the Add-on SDK execute in a window-less context however. So if you are using the SDK you use the internal `window-utils` package:

```
var window = require("window-utils").activeWindow;
var indexedDB = (window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB);
var request = indexedDB.open("MyExtensionDB");
```

Note that all extensions use the same namespace (`chrome://`) as far as IndexedDB goes. So you should choose the database name in such a way that it doesn't collide with the names other extensions might choose.

Starting with Firefox 12 the requirement to have a window is dropped. `nsIIndexedDatabaseManager.initWindowless()` can be used to inject `mozIndexedDB` property into any object. Relevant bug: [bug 587797](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587797).