# Cannot open IndexedDB in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, indexeddb

I get the following error  when i try to open indexeddb from my firefox extension

[Exception... "Illegal value"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://extension/abc.html :: openDb :: line 213"  data: no]

```
const DB_NAME = 'dbName';
const DB_VERSION = 1; 
const DB_STORE_NAME = 'dbStore';

var db;

 function openDb() {
  try{
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
  req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    db = this.result;
  };
  req.onerror = function (evt) {
   console.error("openDb:", evt.target.errorCode);
  };

  req.onblocked = function(evt) {
  // If some other tab is loaded with the database, then it needs to be closed
  // before we can proceed.
  console.log("Please close all other tabs with this site open!");
  alert("Please close all other tabs with this site open!");
  };
 }
catch(err){
    alert(err);
}
 }
```

It goes to the catch part with the above quoted error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, FF states `TypeError: indexedDB is null` with your current code. Also, the Demo from the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/IndexedDB) throws an error too in FF, so I guess the changed some implementation details.

Comment: Have you tried opening the DB without the DB_VERSION parameter?

Comment: I'm interested in how you get a "chrome://extension" error from a Firefox extension? Are you perhaps confusing error messages?

Comment: What is the context of your code?

Comment: @paa Thanks for stopping by IDB tag again. Check out the fiddle in my answer and maybe you can reproduce. I'm an IDB "expert" and am baffled at the moment.

Comment: Hey - does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042390/using-indexeddb-in-a-firefox-extension

Comment: That's got to be it. Knew this to be true with e.g. Web Workers but didn't realize it applied to iframes as well.

Comment: And now the million dollar question, @user3346133 does your code run in the the context of `about:something`, excluding `about:home`?

Comment: IndexedDB works fine in my other firefox extensions. This piece of code is part of abc.html that is being opened in a new tab (window.open("chrome://extension/abc.html")) from a firefox extension. If opening a new tab via this method and invoking the IDB is causing the error, then could you please help me out another way of invoking a new tab and using the IDB from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give a working `indexedDB`

```
Components.utils.importGlobalProperties(["indexedDB"]);
```

I tested only if `open` returns a valid `IDBDatabase` object. Please confirm data store and retrieve.

(this is just a workaround, `indexedDB` accessor method is buggy)

edit: Chrome dialogs have a working `indexedDB`

Comment: Thanks @paa this solution works!! And I have moved that piece of code to the registered js file and I make a function call from by abc.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Based on group debugging it's likely you're testing your IDB code in a window-less Firefox environment. Because IDB depends on the window to create it's sandboxed security environment, you cannot run IDB in such an environment.

Interestingly, I'm able to reproduce the Firefox "TypeError: indexedDB is null" @Christoph mentions when using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/E3Tjs/) for both prefixed and unprefixed `indexedDB` interfaces.

Same code, reproduced below, works fine in Chrome. And, strangely, works fine in FF when executed directly from the console

```
var DB_NAME = 'dbName';
var DB_VERSION = 1;
var DB_STORE_NAME = 'dbStore';

var db;
try {
    var req = self.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        db = this.result;
        console.log('success', evt.target.result);
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.error("error", evt);
    };
    req.onblocked = function (evt) {
        console.log('blocked', evt);
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.name, err.message);
}
```

[image]

Try running your code in a FF console and see if you can confirm. And in the meantime, I'm curious, in what environment are you seeing this error?

Comment: Just adding a ditto - I see it in FF 28.

Comment: Ok - I think this may be a JSFiddle issue. I run my code via a local HTML on my dev server and it runs ok. Can you try it that way?

Comment: Firefox associates indexedDB instances with URIs. The code of a fiddle is evaluated inside a URIless iframe. So no `indexedDB` object for that code. However from console you can hapilly use indexedDB since that code is evaluated in the context of a jsfiddle.net/something window. This limitation does not apply to privileged code (aka extensions). But a couple of extra steps is required.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I noted above than running this manually in console worked fine. Super strange that IDB is nulled out - I wonder if it's a security production of some sort?